# Representation of continuous curves on the unit circle via continuous angle function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an issue with an exercise that is concerned with the representation of continuous paths on the unit circle.

[image]

I started by considering the complex logarithm for $z=e^{i \varphi}, \ \varphi \in (-\pi,\pi]$. Then the complex logarithm can be defined as

$$
\log(z):=\log(|z|)+i \varphi. 
$$

So any function $\varphi$ that has the required property must also satisfy

$$
\varphi(t)=-i \log(\gamma(t)). \tag{1}
$$

I am however a bit confused about how to define $\varphi$ such that $\varphi([0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Of course I could take (1) as the definition. Then $\gamma(t)$ has a polar representation such that

$$
\log(\gamma(t))= \log(1)+i \phi=i \phi, \ \phi \in \mathbb{R}. 
$$

This would give me the desired result. However this seems to be a bit too simplistic. Am I on the right track or is this supposed to be solved in a different way?